# Differentiability implies continuity

Tags: analysis, soft-question

This is a but of a more mathematically juvenile question but I'm trying to get all my intuition in order. When taking a limit we can cancel things that might be zero because in taking a limit, we allow ourselves to avoid trouble spots. If the limit exists, it is very much a number/function which could be zero. So, if I have a function $f$ differentiable at a point $a$ then I have

$$\lim_{z \to a}\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}=f'(z)$$

Now, this implies continuity since

$$\lim_{z \to a}f(z)-f(a)=\lim_{z \to a}\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}\cdot f'(z)\lim_{z \to a}z-a$$

Now, this idea makes perfect sense to me but we know that the limit $z-a$ approaches is $0$. How is it we are comfortable cancelling them? Is it within the $\epsilon, \delta$ language? If my question is unclear let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't distribute the limit since for the denominator,  $(\lim_{z \to a}z-a)$ is zero. Hence you can't multiply by this expression.

Comment: That is exactly what the Conway Complex Analysis book does as well as the Guaghan Analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to see this is by considering, for $z\ne a$,
$$
\varphi(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}-f'(a)
$$
and noting that
$$
\lim_{z\to a}\varphi(z)=0
$$
because $f$ is differentiable at $a$. Then write
$$
f(z)=f(a)+f'(a)(z-a)+\varphi(z)(z-a)
$$
Now take the limit:
$$
\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=
\lim_{z\to a}(f(a)+f'(a)(z-a)+\varphi(z)(z-a))=f(a)
$$

---

Another way (but actually the same) is to consider
$$
\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=
\lim_{z\to a}\left(\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}(z-a)+f(a)\right)
$$
and applying well-known theorem on limits. In no place of the definition of limits you examine the value at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

A limit when $z\to a$ should always be taken through values outside $a$.

True that many times we forget to write $0<|z-a|<\delta$ instead of $|z-a|<\delta$.